# Problema al obtener valor en NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo un problema para obtener o llenar una variable dentro de una promesa.

el codigo es:

```
var _TOKEN = '';

client.metodoGet(clientId, clientSecret)
  .then(function () {

    _TOKEN = client.authentications["XXXXXXX"].accessToken;
    console.log(_TOKEN);

this.token = _TOKEN;

      return _TOKEN;
  })
  .catch(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

y necesito obtener el token para poder mandar esta variable a otro archivo.

Como ven declaro la variable fuera del metodo, y le doy un valor dentro del metodo, pero al imprimir, siempre me sale undefined.

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Las promesas siempre retornan un valor en el then podrías probarlo así

```
client.metodoGet(clientId, clientSecret)
  .then((resultado) => {
    console.log(resultado.authentications["XXXXXXX"].accessToken);
    this.token = resultado.authentications["XXXXXXX"].accessToken;
  })
  .catch((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```